# Boolean AND with exact matches oin Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In our Elasticsearch collection of products, we have an an array of hashes, called "nutrients". A partial example of the data would be:

```
"_source": {
  "quantity": "150.0",
  "id": 1001,
  "barcode": "7610809001066",
  "nutrients": [
    {
      "per_hundred": "1010.0",
      "name_fr": "Énergie",
      "per_portion": "758.0",
      "name_de": "Energie",
      "per_day": "9.0",
      "name_it": "Energia",
      "name_en": "Energy"
    },
    {
      "per_hundred": "242.0",
      "name_fr": "Énergie (kCal)",
      "per_portion": "181.0",
      "name_de": "Energie (kCal)",
      "per_day": "9.0",
      "name_it": "Energia (kCal)",
      "name_en": "Energy (kCal)"
    },
    {
      "per_hundred": "18.0",
      "name_fr": "Matières grasses",
      "per_portion": "13.5",
      "name_de": "Fett",
      "per_day": "19.0",
      "name_it": "Grassi",
      "name_en": "Fat"
    },
```

In the search, we are trying to bring back the products based on an exact match of two of the fields contained in the nutrients array. What I am finding is the conditions seemed to be OR and not AND.

The two attempts have been:

```
   "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
              { "match": { "nutrients.name_fr": "Énergie" } },
              { "match": { "nutrients.per_hundred": "242.0" } }
          ]
        }
    }
  }
```

and

```
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          { "term": { "nutrients.name_fr": "Énergie" } },
          { "term": { "nutrients.per_hundred": "242.0" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Both of these are in fact bringing back entries with Énergie and 242.0, but are also match on different name_fr, eg:

```
    {
      "per_hundred": "242.0",
      "name_fr": "Acide folique",
      "per_portion": "96.0",
      "name_de": "Folsäure",
      "per_day": "48.0",
      "name_it": "Acido folico",
      "name_en": "Folic acid"
    },
```

They are also matching on a non exact match, i.e: matching also on "Énergie (kCal)" when we want to match only on "Énergie"

Answer (score 1):

On your first problem:
You have to make the nutrients field nested, so you can query each object inside it for itself [Elasticsearch Nested Objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html).